# a strange issue with ping6 using the 2001:db8: address

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have 2 Ubuntu machines one acting as IPv6 wireless router (running hostap and radvd on wlan0) and the other is connected to that router.

The router wlan0 interface has the address 2001:db8:1:1::1/64 and the host has the address 2001:db8:1:1::2/64 on wlan0 which is connected to ap1 provided by the router. On wireshark, I can see the router advertisements at the router and the host.

When I ping 2001:db8:1:1::2 at the router it says that "Destination unreachable: Address unreachable" and I can see the neighbour solicitation and advertisement messages exchange.

When I ping 2001:db8:1:1::1 at the host it says the same "Destination unreachable: Address unreachable" and I can see the neighbour solicitation message only

Any idea?

Also, I have tried to do the following into the router

`sudo ip -6 neigh add 2001:db8:1:1::2 lladdr 64:50:03:ec:cc:ss dev wlan0`

and this into the host

`sudo ip -6 neigh add 2001:db8:1:1::1 lladdr 64:50:03:ec:cc:ff dev wlan0`

Then, when I ping I can see the echo request and reply exchange in wireshark only but I cannot see that at the command line, rather it says no packets have been received !!!

Thank you